# ClassNotFoundException & app crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, crash

I'm working with Android Studio on a learning app, but when i run it, it crashes and give me this error code:

```
03-29 22:36:03.546 13455-13455/com.training.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.training.criminalintent, PID: 13455
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.training.criminalintent/com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.training.criminalintent-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2290)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.training.criminalintent-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I looked for a solution but didn't find something adequate for android studio, but most importantly i didn't find the source of the problem, why android studio is behaving like that.

EDIT: The activity exists in the manifest File :

> 

```
<application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".CrimePagerActivity">
>     </activity> </application>
```

I must also precise that before i downgraded the tools folder in the sdk (compatibility problem with another software)[I named the folder tools ==> toolsXXXX and download the version 24.2 and put the tools folder in the sdk folder], it was working..

Comment: @EvilZ answered your question; but here's a link (https://github.com/mehtamanan/CriminalIntent) to the whole project that you're building!

Comment: Thanks, but i'm interested about learning not the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing an uninstall of your application, perform a clean build, gradle sync, and then run your application again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity` exists in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name="com.training.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity" />
```